# 3 arrays into one array using length of each array

Tags: node.js

I've 3 arrays..the length of each is 2..so want to create fourth have 2 object

> ['a','b'] , ['12','1'] , ['c','d']

I want to insert them in my mysql..so I want them to be like this

> [ {'a','12','c'} , {'b','1','d'} ]

Comment: Not really much `mysql in this question, please dont use unnecessary tags

Comment: If you just want to make an array of arrays, you can use lodash.zip: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#zip

but those are arrays, not objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map over one of the arrays, and use the index as the index into the other two.

```js
const a1 = ['a','b'];
const a2 = ['12','1'];
const a3 = ['c','d'];
const result = a1.map((el, i) => [el, a2[i], a3[i]]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work for multiple arrays with any length, as long they all have the same number of elements

```js
function combine(...arrays) {
 // Fisrt check if all arrays you want to merge have the same length
 // otherwise will not be possible to make this operation
 let len = arrays[0].length
 let allSameLength = arrays.some(a => a.length !== len)
 if (allSameLength) { return null }

 let result = []

 for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   // Get all elements from all arrays at index I
   let newArr = arrays.map(e => e[i])
   
   // Push new Array to result
   result.push(newArr)
 }

 return result
}

let r = combine(['a','b'], ['12','1'], ['c','d'])
console.log(r)
```